# Forcing several callbacks to have the same input type without passing generic manually

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following (simplified type):

```
interface RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData> {
  getData?: (data: Data, currentData: TransformedData) => TransformedData;
}

interface RequestAction<Data = any, TransformedData = Data> {
  type: string;
  request: any | any[];
  meta?: RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>;
}


declare function createQuery<Data = any, TransformedData = Data ,Variables extends any[] = any[]>(
  name: string,
  requestConfig: (...params: Variables) => any,
  metaConfig?: (...params: Variables) => RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>,
): (...params: Variables) => RequestAction<Data, TransformedData>;
```

Without passed generics, I could do sth like this now:

```
const fetchAnimals = createQuery(
  'FETCH_ANIMALS',
  (x: number) => ({ url: '/animals', x }),
  (x: string) => ({
    getData: data => ({ id: data.id, name: x }),
  }),
);

fetchAnimals({});
```

which works great, TS will recognize that callbacks input should be the same, while it is not - we have in 1st place `number`, in 2nd `string`, in 3rd empty object.

However, once I pass `Data` generic, TS doesn't catch this error anymore:

```
const fetchAnimals = createQuery<{ id: string, name: string}>(
  'FETCH_ANIMALS',
  (x: number) => ({ url: '/animals', x }),
  (x: string) => ({
    getData: data => ({ id: data.id, name: x }),
  }),
);

fetchAnimals({});
```

and Typescript won't show any error anymore. I don't understand why, because `Data` in theory has nothing to do with `Variables`

You could see [this demo](https://tsplay.dev/mbkK3W) to see this behaviour.

Comment: Don't use `any`.

Comment: In which place? return statements of callbacks are unknown (this is library code) and redundant, and `<Variables extends any[] = any[]` is just to have a way to accept any arguments. I just want to have whatever input type a user desires, I just want to make sure that they are in sync (without passing generic)

Comment: Yes, but both `string` and `number` fit as `any`, if you want them to be the same, simply drop the any

Comment: "and Typescript won't complain"... [are you sure?](https://tsplay.dev/w62L6w) I can't reproduce the issue you're having.  Can you demonstrate it?

Comment: Interesting, maybe I have another older TS version, or maybe simplified types changed something. I will need to dig into it, thanks!

Comment: Please see updated [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mbkK3W) , what's interesting, It stops working once passed `Data` generic. Without passed generic, it works like in your example. So this seems to be the issue. I will update my question probably, but before I need to know why 1st generic passed breaks `Variables` inference.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question.

Comment: @Evert apologies once more for my mistake.

Comment: @klis87 no worries at all =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is all or nothing for generics. Meaning you cannot specify some generics, and let it infer the others. Once you start specifying the generics you have to specify them all.

Because you passed in the data generic argument, it now wants all the generic values, and will not infer them.

There have been lots of requests for a more flexible model, but for now you have to make all generics inferrable, which means somewhere in the params, or simply specify all of them (can use typeof to "read" the type of existing variables.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks! Do you think there might be some workaround? Like with `infer` and some conditionals to force inference?

Comment: I think the return of the method should be inferrable. I'll try to mock it up for you